# Pass by reference or re-assigning? Which is better / more efficient / etc?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Recently I've been using the PHP pass by reference "&" operator and then modifying the array by enriching, deleting or adding to items, but don't know if this is the best way to do things with arrays in PHP, rather than re-assigning them:  Here's an example:

```
 function save_contract($contract_id){

  $this->layout = 'json';
  if(isset($contract_id)){
    $contract_data = array(
     'id'     => (int)$contract_id,
     'errors' => array(),
    );

    $this->_validate_post_data(&$contract_data);


}
```

-OR - Is it better to do this:

```
 function save_contract($contract_id){

  $this->layout = 'json';
  if(isset($contract_id)){
    $contract_data = array(
     'id'     => (int)$contract_id,
     'errors' => array(),
    );

    $contract_data = $this->_validate_post_data($contract_data);

}
```

Comment: Better != more efficient. Passing by reference is more efficient as Niet says, but passing by reference is usually better, since it does not rely on a function 'side effect'. If you do it sparingly it's fine, but not if you are also returning results from the function. Only choose between the two based on performance if you genuinely have a performance issue at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not changing the array, then the two operations are identical. If you are changing, then passing by-reference is more efficient because it doesn't have to copy the array.

That said, reference passing should be handled by the function signature, ie:

```
private function _validate_post_data(&$data) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Failure to do this will result in a Strict Standards error.